# How to close p-dialog on Button Click in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I want to close this dialog box when I click on button.

```
    <p-dialog [(visible)]="displayFact" [modal]="true" [style]="[{width: '50%'}]" [baseZIndex]="1000" [draggable]="false" [resizable]="false" [closable]='true'>
     <div class="card rounded">
      <div>....</div>
      <a class="btn btn-primary w-25 mx-auto rounded mb-3" (click)= "closeDialog()">Close</a>
     </div> 
</p-dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to achieve this.

```
closeDialog(){
    this.displayFact = false
}
```

**API**

Visible boolean false   Specifies the visibility of the dialog.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/dialog

Comment: How can i close if I want this button to be in pop-up? Because i defined my "displayFact" in my main component. And I can't set it to false from the pop-up because it does not exist. Should I just call this function from my pop-up component?